# How to set 3 table data in MVC3 view and make it editable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view in which I want to display 3 data tables. All 3 tables data are being fetched from one table in database. I am thinking of using 3 different partial views in index.cshtml. And can use 1 stored procedure to fetch data. I want to make it editable and want to save the data with a submit button.

Any one knows a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

On the UI side these jQuery plugins can help you a lot:

- http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/
- http://handsontable.com/
- https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Answer (score 0):

u can use ViewModel on your MVC to fetch all of your table and edit in one Viewbag,

> [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3),  [this](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html), [and this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/QHQT270712-Understanding-ViewModel-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html)